# Anychart anychart.scales.dateTime(); how to create two lines with AnyChart that doesn't make the other disappear?

Tags: jquery, anychart-8.2

AnyCHART, I have two databases and I want to link them and display them in a table. unfortunately when I use anychart.scales.dateTime();

the two lines are mixed but erase the lines, only the points remain.. someone could enlighten me

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBA7s.png)

```js
var serieOne =
    [
        { value: 33, x: Date.UTC(2021, 01, 14) },
        { value: 37, x: Date.UTC(2021, 02, 13) },
        { value: 33, x: Date.UTC(2021, 03, 13) },
        { value: 36, x: Date.UTC(2021, 04, 13) },
        { value: 40, x: Date.UTC(2021, 05, 13) }
    ];

var serieTwo =
    [
        { value:30, x: Date.UTC(2021, 01, 1) },
        { value: 31, x: Date.UTC(2021, 03, 1) },
        { value: 32, x: Date.UTC(2021, 04, 1) },
        { value: 33, x: Date.UTC(2021, 05, 1) },
        { value: 44, x: Date.UTC(2021, 06, 1) }
    ];


var ligneColorOne = '#68b022';
var ligneColorTwo = '#0078bb';


anychart.onDocumentReady(function () {

    var chart = anychart.line();

    var lineOne = chart.line(serieOne);
    lineOne.stroke([ligneColorOne], 6);
 
     
    var lineTwo = chart.line(serieTwo);
    lineTwo.stroke([ligneColorTwo], 6);
    
     
    chart.legend(true);
  
    var xDateTimeScale = anychart.scales.dateTime();
    var xDateTimeTicks = xDateTimeScale.ticks();
    xDateTimeTicks.interval(0,1);
 
    chart.xScale(xDateTimeScale);
   
    chart.container("chartserieOne");
    chart.draw();
});
```